# Is there any way to access cookie values from a WCF Web Service method?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, cookies

I'm switching my web services over from .ASMX to .SVC, however several of them depend on cookie values passed in on the HTTP request.

With a WCF web service, `HttpContext.Current` is null.  You can change this, by setting `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` to `true`, however this setting is then incompatible with integrated pipeline mode on IIS7 which I also want to be using.

Does WCF implement some cool new modern way of accessing cookies?

Comment: *Does WCF implement some cool new modern way of accessing cookies?* Nope.  This sounds like one of the notorious WCF gotchas.

Comment: @dbaseman - Yea, the more I read about it the more I'm learning I'm out of luck..  Sigh..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does WCF implement some cool new modern way of accessing cookies?

WCF does have a way to access the cookies, but I don't know if I'd call it "cool new modern". Essentially, within your service operation you can access the `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie]` property, and that will give you the value of the `Cookie` header sent by the client - as a string. At that point you're free to parse it as you wish.

Comment: Thanks!  Marking as answer since this technically satisfies my question.  However, I've decided to instead re-factor the web services to not use cookies, which from my research appears to be a more suggested design.

Comment: Oh also you wrote [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Supporting-different-data-b0351c9a/view/Discussions) blog post right?  I'm actually using your code for this!  I did find one bug with it, which I left under the Q&A (Under *imaudi*)..

Comment: I also am facing the same problem, I tried all the solutions mentioned here. But in my case `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers` does not have a key named cookie or anything like it. Please help

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the right answer you need to make sure that you set the allowCookies attribute of your binding to false.

If it is set to true WCF will take over cookie management and strip cookies out of the header before they reach your code.
See [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e2659b8-6834-464b-a618-1fcd2359a654/bug-in-wcf-cookie-header-is-deleted-in-httprequestmessageproperty-but-not-any-other-headers?forum=wcf)

(Sorry, can't comment yet.)